# Passing a structure pointer as a function argument (Seg fault unknown)

Tags: c, pointers, structure

Header file #1 "city.h"

```
typedef struct City{

    double* lat;
    double* lon;
    double* pop;


    char* airport;
    char* name;


}City;
```

Header file #2 "vector.h"

```
typedef struct Vector{


  City* cityArray[26];  // 26 pointers to struct City


 }Vector;
```

C file

```
#include "vector.h"
#include "city.h"
#include <stdlib.h>


void init(Vector *ptr) {

ptr->cityArray[0]->name = "hi"; // Error Seg Fault!

}
```

Hi, Your suggestion did work, but for some reason I'm getting Seg faults now even though the I'm 100% sure the code didn't change. Could you see whats wrong?

Comment: Another issue is that `name` is `char **` while `"hi"` is `const char *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
  ptr->cityArray[0]->name = "hi";       // ptr is pointer to struct vector
```

As `cityArray` is a member variable of struct `Vector` , access it using a struct variable or pointer .

Can't do this 
`cityArray[0]->name = "hi";`because `cityArray` is not any independent array of pointers.

### EDIT

As you get segmentation fault , you need to allocate memory to struct pointer `ptr` as well as to `char *` present in struct `city`.

In function do it like this -

```
ptr=malloc(sizeof(Vector));
ptr->cityArray[0]->name=malloc(3);     // size 3 to store "hi" you can give desired size.
```

But remember to `free` allocated memory.

Comment: Hi, Your suggestion did work, but for some reason I'm getting Seg faults now even though the I'm 100% sure the code didn't change. Could you see whats wrong?

Comment: @JackW You need to allocate memory to it . Please see the edit in answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, *vector.h* appears before *city.h*. You need to put *city.h* before *vector.h* to make the definition of `city` visible to `vector`.

That said, `cityArray` itself is not an independent *variable*, it is called a member variable. You need to have a variable of the structure type to make use of `cityArray`. Something like

```
Vector Vec;
Vec.cityArray[0]->name ....
```

and so on. Also make a note about the type of the variable and the initializer used. They both should match.

Comment: Hi, Your suggestion did work, but for some reason I'm getting Seg faults now even though the I'm 100% sure the code didn't change. Could you see whats wrong?